# Can we make animations through the 3D shadow of 4D objects?

Tags: functions

When we rotate or move a 4D object along it's 4:th axis we get a neat little animation in 3D space (look at the tesseract or the 5-cell for reference).

Can we create a 4D shape that, when rotated or moved along it's 4:th axis, makes a recognizeble animation, such as a man running, or a dog walking, or any other animation we could recognize as something relatable with our 3D minds?

If we can, which I for now believe should be possible, then how coud we calculate such a 4D shape from it's 3D animation?

Comment: For rotations it might be difficult, but for translations along the fourth axis, the answer is trivially yes: at time $t$ you just take $(x,y,z,w)=(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,t)$ where in the $(x,y,z)$ slots you put the points that you want to see in your animation.

Comment: Haha! Simple enough. :) Just an ordinary animation with other words. Well, exept that each frame correspond to a point on an axis. This gave me an intresting idea for some software I want to develop. Thanks for your comment. You should post it as an answer so this topic could be marked as solved. :)

Comment: Rotating around an axis does not really make sense in four dimensions. You can only rotate around a plane. Unlike translation, I don't think you can create arbitrary shapes, because the projection of the plane of revolution will remain constant (unless you rotate the plane of revolution simultaneously, or rotate in two planes, then I'm not sure what happens). Just like rotating a three-dimensional solid around an axis will not change the picture of the shadow in the projection of the axis. (Although in this case, the axis can be parallel to the projection direction.)

Comment: @JoelSahlin: OK, I posted an answer.

Comment: When you rotate a 3D object along only one axis, it's 2D shadow will be altered unless the 3D object is shaped in such a way that makes no difference to the shadow (compare rotating a small statue to for example a sphere). The one axis that could be considered an exception is the axis intersecting the projection plane. Rotating along this axis would only rotate the shadow, but I think it still counts. In 4D, the mesh instead turns inside out sort of instead of being rotated. You can look at visualizations of the tesseract. I am pretty sure it's visualized by rotating it's 4:th axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For translations along the fourth axis, the answer is trivially yes: at time $t$ you just take $(x,y,z,w)=(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,t)$ where in the $(x,y,z)$ slots you put the points that you want to see in your animation.

For rotations, it seems like a more difficult question.